# nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm working through https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04. I've completed the tut but I'm getting a 502 error.

My nginx  server block configuration file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 198..xxx.xxx.xxx mysite.org;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/deploy/mysite3;
}

location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite3.sock;
}
}

deploy@server:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-02-06 17:30:53 EST; 4s ago
  Process: 7374 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7383 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7380 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7384 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─7384 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           └─7385 nginx: worker process

Feb 06 17:30:53 server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 06 17:30:53 server systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Feb 06 17:30:53 server systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

nginx error log shows:

```
2017/02/06 21:10:32 [error] 7385#7385: *15 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 64.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 198.xxx.xxx.xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite3.sock:", host: "mysite.org"
```

It looks to me that uwsgi is running ok:

```
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0xc7ac10 pid: 7435 (default app)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 7435)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: Mon Feb  6 17:43:42 2017 - [emperor] vassal mysite3.ini has been spawned
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 7439, cores: 1)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 7440, cores: 1)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 7441, cores: 1)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 7442, cores: 1)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 7443, cores: 1)
Feb 06 17:43:42 server uwsgi[7434]: Mon Feb  6 17:43:42 2017 - [emperor] vassal mysite3.ini is ready to accept requests
```

How can I fix this?

edit:

```
root@server:~# mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
root@server:~# printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf
root@server:~# systemctl daemon-reload
root@server:~# systemctl restart nginx
root@server:~# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-02-07 08:18:26 EST; 6s ago
  Process: 10076 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5
  Process: 10084 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10082 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (cod
  Process: 10079 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process
 Main PID: 10083 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─10083 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pr
           └─10085 nginx: worker process

Feb 07 08:18:26 server systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a
Feb 07 08:18:26 server systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a r
root@server:~#
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

That warning with the nginx.pid file is a know bug (at least for Ubutnu if not for other distros as well). More details here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864

Workaround (on a ssh console, as root, use the commands bellow):

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" > /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart nginx
```

Then check if you still see that nginx.pid error and also if nginx is actually running and if you can connect to port 80 on your server.

I would also check if this actually exists and the permissions on it:

```
/run/uwsgi/mysite3.sock
```

If nginx is running and uWSGI is running as well then I guess it's a configuration problem

I understand you want to use Django so I would recommend to review your actual configuration and compare it with the one from here:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

I hope it helps!

Comment: I needed to first do this:

mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d

Comment: I am using `apt install nginx` with fresh UBUNTU 16 LTS... And need to correct this bug. How to **install NGINX whithout this bug**?

Comment: The paragraph about uWSGI needs some more explanation.
I'm pretty sure it's not required and I also don't use it.

Comment: This works. I got a permissions denied message when I tried the printf statement with just a 'sudo' before it. So, I had to go into root ('sudo su') first. It got executed then. The remaining worked with plain 'sudo'.

Comment: In case anyone comes here using openresty with the same issue. Also fixed by adding file as `/lib/systemd/system/openresty.service.d/override.conf`

Comment: `printf "[Service]\nExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1\n" | \
    sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf` fixed my problem

Comment: You can also use `systemctl edit` to open an editor and automatically reload (not restart) the unit.