# Nginx not displaying welcome page after initial installation

Tags: nginx

I'm not getting the welcome page after the installation at Ubuntu 17., just display "This page isn’t working..ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" on Chrome

Below is my setup:

1. firewall is disabled

> sudo ufw disable
>   Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup

2. service is up and running

   ```
   nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
              └─override.conf
      Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-02-22 10:22:31 UTC; 1min 6s ago
     Process: 1356 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 0.1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 1270 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 1167 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 1339 (nginx)
       Tasks: 2
      Memory: 9.2M
         CPU: 32ms
      CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
              ├─1339 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
              └─1345 nginx: worker process                           

   Feb 22 10:22:29 jitsinew systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
   Feb 22 10:22:31 jitsinew systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
   ```
3. all the config is default, as below:

   ```
   {
   user www-data;
   worker_processes auto;
   pid /run/nginx.pid;
   include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

   events {
       worker_connections 768;
       # multi_accept on;
   }

   http {

       ##
       # Basic Settings
       ##

       sendfile on;
       tcp_nopush on;
       tcp_nodelay on;
       keepalive_timeout 65;
       types_hash_max_size 2048;
       # server_tokens off;

       # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
       # server_name_in_redirect off;

       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       default_type application/octet-stream;

       ##
       # SSL Settings
       ##

       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       ##
       # Logging Settings
       ##

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

       ##
       # Gzip Settings
       ##

       gzip on;
       gzip_disable "msie6";

       # gzip_vary on;
       # gzip_proxied any;
       # gzip_comp_level 6;
       # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
       # gzip_http_version 1.1;
       # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

       ##
       # Virtual Host Configs
       ##

       include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
   }
   ```
4. there is a file named default under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/, config as below:

   ```
   server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   root /var/www/html;
   server_name _;
   location / {
       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
   }
   ```

Any idea?

Comment: add please what do you have in `server` section from file `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Comment: There is a file named default, actually I didn't change anything after initial installation, config as below: server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

Comment: Have you checked the nginx log files?

Comment: @Evert, the error log file is empty

Comment: @RidgeA, I just supplemented the default file in the main topic #4

Comment: I presume the access log is also empty (or non-existent)?

Comment: The "Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument" leads (among others) to a related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078674/nginx-service-failed-to-read-pid-from-file-run-nginx-pid-invalid-argument). Check your `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d` and see if adding a tiny sleep helps.

Comment: Sorry, there is an entry under error log: 2018/02/22 09:37:38 [notice] 27389#27389: signal process started; and an entry under access log: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2018:08:59:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Wget/1.19.1 (linux-gnu)"

Comment: Well, localhost seems happy (http status of 200), but that's probably not your intention to use it only for localhost.

Comment: To see if it's a system-wide problem and not nginx's, you can stop nginx, then run `sudo python3 -m http.server --bind yourdomain.com 80` to serve the current directory at yourdomain.com. If you can't access that from outside, you know the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Evert I follow the instructions and the PID error disappeared, please check the updated topic, but still can't visit the welcome page

Comment: Check if http or https rule is added in security group if you are using aws ec2.

Comment: My issue was to open port 80 in security group of VPC in AWS. I had 443 thinking 80 will not be used. Ofcourse, NGINX default listens on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem but i just started nginx by typing `service nginx start` to start the server and then typed localhost in my browser & it worked.

Answer (score 0):

add

`index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;`

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name _;
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```