# Connecting Nginx and Django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

This is my first time working in Nginx. I know that in order to connect Django and Nginx easily I require uWSGI.

## Setup

**uWSGI**:

I think my uWSGI setup was completely fine, I've used it to run my Django website on HTTP port `80`:

`uwsgi --http :80 --root /root/Env/firstsite --chdir /root/mysite -w mysite.wsgi`

But since this is not a very practical method for the "best" security, I had to use Nginx. In this case I've used "The uWSGI Emperor" mode and then i've created a new file `/etc/uwsgi/sites/mysite.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
project = mysite
base = /root

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

In this case, Instead of HTTP ports I've used unix socket which uses `uwsgi` protocol.

Finally, I've created `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` file (which from my understanding initiates uwsgi on startup):

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Nginx**:

My Nginx setup was pretty simple, I've just modified the existing server block to fit uWSGI configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock;
    }
}
```

**Initiation**:

```
sudo systemctl start nginx
sudo systemctl start uwsgi
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl enable uwsgi
```

This process doesn't output any errors.

## Problem:

Webserver returns default html response of Nginx - when I expect it to return default html response of Django. Is there any reason for this? I feel like I'm stumbling across a very simple problem here since I couldn't find it anywhere on stackoverflow.

## Possible causes:

1. `/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock` in nginx configuration doesn't exist for some reason, which makes me think that this can be the cause.
2. In `systemctl status nginx` there is an error `Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument` which should be the cause for the problem above? (`systemctl status wsgi` has no errors).
3. From the problems above, I'm thinking that these problems are caused by my Nginx configuration, Is this correct?
4. It directs to `50x.html` which is for errors 500, 502, 503, 504 (in this case it is HTTP 502, bad gateway - this has to do something with configuration).

**Main probable cause:**

In `systemctl status nginx` there is an error `Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument` which should be the cause for the problem above? (`systemctl status wsgi` has no errors).

Checked [this problem & solution](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/heres-fix-nginx-error-failed-read-pid-file-linux/) but it doesn't work.

Please make sure that `/run/uwsgi/` directory is empty, maybe this is the reason.

Thank you!

Comment: May be somwhere nginx is still pointing to its default. Check if there is any server block defined.

Comment: Does the django settings have 'mysite.com' and 'www.mysite.com' in your ALLOWED_HOSTS list.

Comment: @HashSplat Yes `mysite.com` is in the ALLOWED_HOSTS array.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty I don't think so, I checked and there is only one server block. It returns '50x.html` by the way, which may be due to the internal server error.

Comment: Assuming after you made the changes you did a nginx reload or restart

Comment: @ShawnC. I did `sudo systemctl restart nginx` and `sudo systemctl restart uwsgi`.

Comment: How about a `nginx -T` to see what the loaded config looks like

Comment: @ShellRox check the logs... you might find something there.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty As mentioned in the question, In `systemctl status nginx` I found `Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument`. Is this relevant error?

Comment: @ShellRox It might be because of invalid values in pid file. Shutdown the nginx and delete the pid file. Then restart the nginx again.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty Did `rm -rif /run/nginx.pid;sudo systemctl restart nginx;` but the error remains the same.

Comment: @ShawnC. Isn't nginx -T output of nginx configuration file? In that case I think everything looks fine there. Although there must be some error.

Comment: @ShellRox do not issue restart, try start. It might be because nginx and systemd are fighting for PID file. What is the host system?

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty I'm using CentOS7 distribution. [Also I've found out that there is a bug of multithreading/multiprocessing race conditions that are created between nginx and systemd](https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/heres-fix-nginx-error-failed-read-pid-file-linux/). Tried the solution, although it didn't work.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty Also, as mentioned in the question `/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock` doesn't exist, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: If you are still facing issues when setting up new server, you might want to have a look at this simple step by step guide to [get your server up and running with Django, uWSGI & Nginx.](https://medium.com/@sumitsk20/django-uwsgi-nginx-postgresql-setup-on-aws-ec2-ubuntu16-04-with-python-3-6-6c58698ae9d3)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem!

Nginx server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock;
    }
}
```

didn't match `uWSGI` configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
project = mysite
base = /root

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

As visible, the path to the unix socket that is specified in Nginx configuration is incorrect. Therefore, these socket paths must be matched in configuration: `/run/uwsgi/%(project).sock`.

Comment: What about the nginx pid issue??

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty For some reason nginx pid issue was caused by the problem above. Once I fixed this problem there was no nginx pid error anymore. [This answer contains the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42084804/6083655)